# How to truncate/resize a QList<> properly

Tags: qt, size, limit, qlist

After reading a number of questions on here such as [Why doesn't QList have a resize() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683161/why-doesnt-qlist-have-a-resize-method), I am wondering about the following.

Normally, in STL code I could have something like this to limit the size of `results` processed:

```
std::list<int> results = something()
results.resize(std::min(result.size(), 5000));
```

Now I have a Qt project with a QList:

```
QList<int> results = something()
while(results.size() > 5000) {
    results.removeLast();
}
expensiveOperation(results);
```

Is this really the best way to to this with <s>Qt containers</s> a `QList`?
The reason is that I need to pass this eventually to a framework function expecting a `QList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QList` != `std::list`. There's `QLinkedList` which is more like the std. version. For most operations `QVector` is preferred over `QList` as the container type to use in Qt. Read https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/ for a full explanation.

If you're stuck with `QList` for some reason... then yeah...  :(  It *may* be quicker to get a new list with `QList::mid()`. And there's always `QList::toVector()` or `toStdList()`.  :)

Comment: Yes, I understand QList is more like a `boost::ptr_deque`, I just thought the loop is such a shoehorned way to resize the container... I also clarified why a QList is required here. Thanks.

Comment: Added a couple ideas. Well you said you have to pass a QList to a function, but how you build it might be different. It may be quicker to build a vector or linked list and then convert it.

Comment: I will accept your answer as "it's not possible". With only prejudice and no empirical test data at hand, I suspect `toVector()`, `toStdList()` et. al. to be even more expensive calls. Of course the best way will be to not even insert the data into the list in the first place by changing to `something(int max_results)` , but I was very curious about the QList behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
template<typename T>
static void truncate(QList<T> &list, int length) {
    if (0 <= length && length < list.length()) {
        list.erase(list.begin() + length, list.end());
    }
}
```